# Dealing with a variable amount of entries for a given attribute

Tags: survey, missing-data, data-preprocessing, sql, database

I want to analyze a .csv file with the results of a customer survey.

One of the questions is: "Tell us the top 3 reasons you chose us.".

The answers are short paragraphs of text listing a ranging number of reasons (not always 3).

An example answer could be "1. Speed, 2. Customer service, 3. Price".

Another might be: "I liked your customer service, and it wasn't that expensive!"

I would like to be able to turn this data into an overview like this:

```
REASONS
Customer Service: 2
Price: 2
Speed: 1
```

I'm facing two problems:

1. I'm interpreting and splitting up the reasons manually in a spreadsheet. Any tips on how to do this more efficiently are very welcome.
2. I have a field "Reasons" which I want to contain a variable amount of values per record. I don't think spreadsheet software such as Libre Calc supports that, and I suspect I might need to export this to SQL. Am I right in suspecting that? And how would I achieve the desired multiple-fields-per-attribute requirement in SQL?

Comment: I don't follow your overview. Is it that 2 people mentioned customer service among their reasons & only 1 person mentioned speed, or something else?

Comment: Yes! That's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer point number two first.  What you want to do is quickly peruse the first several dozen records in the .csv file, and get a broad idea of what most of the possible reasons were.  Let's say you come up with $N$ reasons, including the three that you had originally listed (customer service, price, speed, etc.).  Next, you make a table (can be a spreadsheet, SQL table, whatever you like; it doesn't matter) with $N+2$ columns.  The first column should be the customer ID number, or the row number in your original .csv file.  Just use whatever identifier will allow you to make a one-to-one correspondence between the rows in your old .csv file and the new table that you are constructing.  The next $N$ columns should be the $N$ most common reasons that you have already constructed.  The final column should be one more reason: "other", a catchall for reasons that don't fit any of the other columns.

You should treat each of your $N$ reason columns as binary variables: i.e., the only possible values should be boolean, either "yes"/"no", or "true"/"false", or 0/1.  It doesn't really matter what convention you choose, just pick one and stick with it.

Whether or not you need to export this to SQL or not depends on what you are going to do with the data.  SQL is a tool for *archiving* data in tables, whereas a spreadsheet is a tool for *analyzing* data in tables.  SQL has support to permit many people to make and delete entries in a table online simultaneously, in such a way that they don't collide with each other.  Do you need to do that, or is this just a one-off analysis project?  If it's the latter, then you want a spreadsheet, not SQL.

Now for part one of your question.  Someone is going to have to do this manually, no question.  You will either have to do it yourself, or hire someone for a one-off freelance gig.  If your time is precious, there are online web services such as [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/) or [freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com/) that specialize in connecting people like you with people who are willing to do data entry for a living.  If you decide to hire someone, and you want to be *really* thorough about it, you might even consider hiring two different people to do the same job twice, and then cross-check their answers against each other to determine the statistical error rate in your data transcription process (though that's probably overkill for most business analysis purposes).

Comment: Thanks for the input. It sounds like all I need is a spreadsheet. Would this also allow me to, given a column "gender", to get the "reason" counts per gender?

Comment: Why not just sum the values (0 or 1) in each of the $N+1$ reason columns?  That will give you the input data for a bar graph (with one bar per column/reason) showing the relative popularity of each reason. Isn't that the kind of overview that you want?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it answers my initial question. But I now realize I want it to be flexible. I want to be able to access, for instance, all reasons per gender (given a "gender" column)

Comment: You can do that pretty easily too.  Add another column for gender, assuming that you know it.  Then in Microsoft Excel, select the gender column, then go to the "Data" menu and select "Filter" from the "Sort and Filter" tab.  This will allow you to screen out rows with only males or only females.  (The analogous command in SQL is the "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..." idiom, though I really do think what you almost certainly want at this point is a spreadsheet, not SQL.)